# I have migrated to https some pages of my site but Google is still showing http version

Tags: web, https, google-search-console, migrate

I don't want to migrate the whole site at same time, only some pages for now.

I have done:

1. install valid certificate
2. securized all resources into the html code of these pages.
3. add rel canonical tag
4. redirect 301 of some pages from http to https version through .htaccess

Google Chrome shows green secured status when access to these pages. Everything it's ok.

I haven't added new site property for https version in Google Search Console because if I do it Google will go to index my whole https site, and i don't want that to happen.

I made these changes 4 days ago and Google still is showing in search results the http version of my migrated pages.

I don't know if we have to add a new property in Google Search Console mandatory or if I just have to wait to google bot recognize the 301 redirect an reindexe pages.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to add links with https in sitemap.xml and add this sitemap in robots.txt and wait googlebot

Comment: I also did it a few days ago but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. After 5 days from changes Google is showing https version of my pages. Regards